What library or framework can I use to parse C++ source code in .NET?
I need to parse C++ source code using C#.
I tried CppAst.net. It seems that it can parse header files, but not source files.
using CppAst;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CppParserCppASTdotNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cppSourceCode = @"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class HelloWorld {
public:
    void greet() {
        cout << ""Hello, World!"" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    HelloWorld obj;
    obj.greet();
    return 0;
}
";

            // Parse a C++ files
            var compilation = CppParser.Parse(cppSourceCode);
            // Print diagnostic messages
            foreach (var message in compilation.Diagnostics.Messages)
                Console.WriteLine(message);

            // Print All enums
            foreach (var cppEnum in compilation.Enums)
                Console.WriteLine(cppEnum);

            // Print All functions
            foreach (var cppFunction in compilation.Functions)
                Console.WriteLine(cppFunction);

            // Print All classes, structs
            foreach (var cppClass in compilation.Classes)
                Console.WriteLine(cppClass);

            // Print All typedefs
            foreach (var cppTypedef in compilation.Typedefs)
                Console.WriteLine(cppTypedef);
        }
    }
}


Ouput
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CppParserCppASTdotNet\CppParserCppASTdotNet\bin\Debug>CppParserCppASTdotNet.exe
cppast.input(2, 10): warning: non-portable path to file '<IOSTREAM>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk
#include <iostream>
        -^-

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\utility(81, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_It::iterator_category'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\utility(82, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_It::value_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\utility(83, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_It::distance_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\utility(224, 32): error: template parameter redefines default argument
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\utility(231, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_Tr::int_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\utility(289, 32): error: template parameter redefines default argument
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(25, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::size_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(26, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::difference_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(27, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::pointer'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(28, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::const_pointer'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(29, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::reference'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(30, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::const_reference'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(31, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::value_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(32, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::pointer'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(33, 10): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name '_A::const_pointer'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xstring(599, 8): error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'basic_string<_E, _Tr, _A>::size_type'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xlocale(296, 15): error: template specialization requires 'template<>'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\xlocale(519, 15): error: template specialization requires 'template<>'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include\streambuf(16, 32): error: template parameter redefines default argument
(0, 0): error: too many errors emitted, stopping now
cppast.input(1, 1): warning: Compilation aborted due to one or more errors listed above.

C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CppParserCppASTdotNet\CppParserCppASTdotNet\bin\Debug>

How can I parse C++ source code in .NET?
